# What are "jetsam priorities"?

Tags: process, launchd, xnu

**Can someone explain what "jetsam priorities" are?**

They are something that is enforced by *launchd*. I suspect that they are a way of throttling down the CPU for a particular process, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source file found when googling for "jetsam priority", I find `jetsam_kill_top_proc()`, which indicates it's used to jettison (kill) processes when memory runs low.